# Generating simulation data based on a specified distribution

Tags: r, simulation

In attempting to replicate the "Digit Recognition" example given on slide 28 of this [lecture](http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~jiali/course/stat597e/notes2/trees.pdf) on CART, I'm unable to figure out how to create a dataset with 200 samples based on a specified distribution.

```
# columns to be used for specified distribution
Digit <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0)
X1 <- c(0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1)
X2 <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1)
X3 <- c(1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1)
X4 <- c(0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0)
X5 <- c(0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1)
X6 <- c(1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
X7 <- c(0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1)

# df is the specified distribution 
df <- cbind(Digit,X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6,X7)
```

The 10 digits are shown by different on-off combinations of seven horizontal and vertical lights. Each digit is represented by a 7-dimensional vector of zeros and ones.

The *i*th sample is [image: formula]. If [image: form2], the *j*th light is on; if [image: form3], the *j*th light is off.

The lecture states that the data for this example are generated by a malfunctioning calculator. Each of the seven lights has probability 0.1 of being in the wrong state independently. The training set contains 200 samples according to the specified distribution.

Could you please help me understand how to configure this simulation data? Thank you for your time.

Comment: `matrix(rbinom(70,prob=0.1,size=1),ncol=10)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate to be that guy who answers their own post but I just found the same example used on page 15 [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpart/vignettes/longintro.pdf) in the "rpart" documentation. I'll continue writing up the answer but I'll delete the question at the end of the day unless I hear differently from the community. Sorry about my oversight.

```
# the data for this example is generated by a malfunctioning calculator 
set.seed(1953) # An auspicious year
n <- 200
y <- rep(0:9, length=200)
temp <- c(1,1,1,0,1,1,1,
          0,0,1,0,0,1,0,
          1,0,1,1,1,0,1,
          1,0,1,1,0,1,1,
          0,1,1,1,0,1,0,
          1,1,0,1,0,1,1,
          0,1,0,1,1,1,1,
          1,0,1,0,0,1,0,
          1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
          1,1,1,1,0,1,0)

# The true light pattern 0-9
lights <- matrix(temp, 10, 7, byrow = TRUE)
# Noisy lights
temp1 <- matrix(rbinom(n*7, 1, 0.9), n, 7)
temp1 <- ifelse(lights[y+1, ] == 1, temp1, 1-temp1)
# Random lights
temp2 <- matrix(rbinom(n*17, 1, 0.5), n, 17)
x <- cbind(temp1, temp2)
```

Comment: there's nothing wrong with answering your own question.  I would recommend *not* deleting this.